# How to create an Apple 'Associated Domain File' without an extension

Tags: server, apple-appclips

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains), I need to add a file to my website called *apple-app-site-association* **without an extension** in order to utilize App Clips:

> To add the associated domain file to your website, create a file named apple-app-site-association (without an extension).

However, I can't seem to accomplish that. According to iPage support, it's not possible to have a file without an extension.

**Question:** Is it truly necessary for this file to be without an extension, or is there an acceptable extension I can use? What would you recommend I do, here, since iPage says it's not possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by uploading the file via FTP (FileZilla).